# Proving a certain surface is complete

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let's consider the following abstract surface on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\left\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \ | \ u^2+v^2 < 1\right\}$:
$$S = \left\{\mathbb{D}, \left\{E=G=\frac{4}{(1-u^2-v^2)^2}, \ F = 0\right\}\right\}$$
($E,G,F$ denote the coefficients of the first fundamental form.)

Is $S$ necessarily complete? I have tried using arguments related to Gaussian curvatures to show that $S$ must be complete (Using the Brioschi Formula, we can get that the Gaussian curvature $K$ is always equal to $-1$)....but I got stuck on it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi there! Would you please clarify a bit on proving that the surface is complete? I googled Poincare disc model online, while none of the links seems to provide a convincing proof...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the square in the denominator of $E=G=\dfrac4{(1-u^2-v^2)^2}$.

By [Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hopf-Rinow_theorem), we just need to show there is a point $p\in\mathbb{D}$ for which $\mathbb{D}$ is geodesically complete at $p$, i.e., you can extend geodesics infinitely starting at $p$ in every direction.  The point $p=0$ (i.e., $(u,v)=(0,0)$) is a convenient choice here.  Then noting Euclidean reflections across diameters of $\mathbb{D}$ are isometries, we know the geodesics through $0$ are the diameters.  So it suffices to show the length of a Euclidean radius is infinite in this metric:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}r}{1-r^2}=\infty
$$

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for your help! I have checked Hopf-Rinow Theorem you mentioned above. Would you please clarify a little bit more on your answer? I already know that by Hopf-Rinow, we only need to show that for every $p \in S$, the exponential map $\exp_{p}$ at $p$ is well defined for every $v \in T_{p}(S)$. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Hopf & Rinow actually proved that you only need to check a single point $p$, not every point (look at the proof: it starts with fix a point $p\in M$ and promptly only works with $\exp_p$ and not any other $\exp_q$'s).  That's why I linked to the EoM version instead of the Wikipedia version which doesn't mention this.  See, e.g., Do Carmo's book.